# Multimap and shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, function-pointers, multi-index

I want to sort my objects in `boost::multi_map` refer to some index. But I'm storing not pure objects, but wrapped into `boost::shared_ptr`. Here is the code:

```
typedef boost::multi_index_container<boost::shared_ptr<Object>,
            boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
                boost::multi_index:: ordered_non_unique<
                    boost::multi_index::mem_fun<boost::shared_ptr<Object>, int, &boost::shared_ptr<Object>::getIndex>
                >
            >
        > ObjectWrapperSet;
```

But it fails at point: `&boost::shared_ptr<Object>::getIndex`. This is logically, that type doesn't have `getIndex` function. But how to refer to that function this way?

I tried it with simple `Object::getIndex`:

```
could not convert template argument ‘&Object::getIndex’ to ‘int (boost::shared_ptr<Object>::*)()’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
boost::multi_index::mem_fun<boost::shared_ptr<Object>, int, &boost::shared_ptr<Object>::getIndex>
```

to

```
boost::multi_index::mem_fun<Object, int, &Object::getIndex>
```

According to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/key_extraction.html#chained_pointers) it should work.